# Incorrect logging and summaries in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow v0.11.0. I am training two networks: `D` and `G`. The basic problem is I am not able to record the values that I am displaying and that's causing a mess. The printed value of the `d` and `g` losses are completely different than what I am logging.

```
#Defining Losses
loss_d1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_1, 0.9*tf.ones_like(in_1)))
loss_d2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_2, tf.zeros_like(in_2)))
loss_g = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_2, tf.ones_like(in_2)))

#combining losses
loss_d = loss_d1 + loss_d2

#creating summaries
loss_d1_sum = tf.scalar_summary("loss_d1", loss_d1)
loss_d2_sum = tf.scalar_summary("loss_d2", loss_d2)
loss_d_sum = tf.scalar_summary("loss_d", loss_d)
loss_g_sum = tf.scalar_summary("loss_g", loss_g)

#defining the optimizers
op_g = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss_g, var_list=vars_g)
op_d = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss_d, var_list=vars_d)

#merging summaries
self.g_sum = tf.merge_summary([loss_g])
self.d_sum = tf.merge_summary([loss_d, loss_d1, loss_d2])
self.writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./logs', sess.graph)
```

I am updating the `D` once and `G` twice:

```
# Update D network
_, summary_str = self.sess.run([op_d, d_sum], feed_dict= fd)
self.writer.add_summary(summary_str, counter)

# Update G network
_, summary_str = self.sess.run([op_g, g_sum], feed_dict= fd)
self.writer.add_summary(summary_str, counter)

# Update G network again
_, summary_str = self.sess.run([op_g, g_sum], feed_dict= fd)
self.writer.add_summary(summary_str, counter)
```

I am running the following `2` times. Each iteration has 1 `D` update and 2 `G` updates.

```
# Printing stats to stdout
[loss_d, loss_g] = sess.run([loss_d, loss_g], feed_dict = fd)
print 'd_loss:{}, g_loss:{}'.format(loss_d, loss_g)
```

This gives me the output:

```
d_loss: 1.43663359, g_loss: 0.68026298
d_loss: 1.72329867, g_loss: 0.55464995
```

---

I am now extracting the values using the following code to plot using `matplotlib`.

```
for entry in tf.train.summary_iterator(log_file)
    for v in entry.summary.value:
        if v.tag == 'loss_d'
            g.append(v.simple_value)
        elif v.tag == 'loss_g'
            d.append(v.simple_value)

print len(d), len(d)       # 2 4
print 'd_loss', d          # d_loss [2.196472406387329, 1.200419545173645]
print 'g_loss', g          # g_loss [6.2136077880859375, 2.953800678253174, 5.429494857788086, 2.6036014556884766]
```

Am I implementing the logging scheme correctly? I thought the value of `loss_d` and `loss_g` might have changed since I have run the the ops after logging. But then that means the last op must have the values saved and must not change while doing a `sess.run`. The `fd` is constant throughout an iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using summaries properly.

A summary op produces tensors that contain Summary protocol buffers; merge summary combines multiple summary ops into a single target that will produce all of the summary protobufs together.

You create some scalar summary ops, but you aren't ever evaluating them. Instead, you're passing non-summary tensors (loss_g, etc) into merge_summary, which is undefined behavior since those ops should only be taking summary ops. If you want to manually create merged summary targets, you should pass the outputs from tf.summary.scalar(x) into merge_summary.

You may also want to check out [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) or [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4).